# WordPress slider code returning no results

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress and I have the following PHP code on my theme's homepage which I'm struggling to understand. The code makes a query for images to be used on a slider however the query is returning no results even though I've tried adding images wherever I could in the backend including creating posts with featured images but still nothing is showing up.

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper">

    <?php $ij=0;
        $slider = array('post_type'=>'slide','order'=>'ASC');
        $slider_query = new wp_query($slider);
        while($slider_query->have_posts()): $slider_query->the_post();
            $feat_imag1 = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($slider_query->ID));                
    ?>

    <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $feat_imag1; ?>)"></div>
    <?php $ij++;  endwhile;?>

</div>
```

My question is what is this block of code related to within the admin panel? I've read that `post_type=>'slide'` is not standard so is this for some 3rd party slide plugin? If so would you know the name of it?

Comment: In my opinion, without more context here, it will be difficult to answer. What is your theme, where did you find this code, what has lead you to that code, etc..

Comment: It's a custom theme created for a client by another developer (unable to contact) which the client wants me to put online. I was given no information on how it was originally set up or the type of plugins used so I've had to comb over the source code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no post type called 'slide' by default. 
It seems developer created it for slider. You can read more about creating custom post types [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)

The above said code in your theme's home page means if there are slide(s) with images( featured image or attachments) , they will be populated with wp_query
Take a look at how wp_query works from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Assuming that your project is in development stage you can try view/add/edit the slides in these path

**To view slides:**

localhost/project-name/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=slide

**To add slide**

localhost/project-name/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=slide

In short the other developer created a custom post type called slide and listed them using wp_query for showing slider. If there is no slides/images there will be no output for that given code.

So try adding some slides and look for slider in home page.

Look for 'slide' in your theme functions.php file.

If you are unable to find the slider after these steps, please share us screenshot of your active plugins list.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This unfortunately doesn't work as I have tried multiple times to add a slide with an image and still no images appear on the home page gallery. In fact clicking the link to the post displays an unformatted page so I have no idea what's going on. This is why I thought they may have used a 3rd party slide plugin. I think re-coding this myself would be quicker and easier than figuring out what the developers have done.